# Sum of two dependent normally distributed variables

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a question involving the elegant result of the distribution of the sum of independent normal variables, when using the mgf.

My question is as follows. Let ${X}^T = (X_1,X_2)$ be bivariate normal distributed with mean ${\mu} = ( \mu_1,\mu_2)$ and covariance matrix
$
\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} \\
\Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 & \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2\\
\rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2
\end{bmatrix}
$

Furter let $Y = X_1 + X_2$, where $X_1 \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $X_2 \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ where independent then the mgf of $Y$ is 
\begin{align}
M_Y(t) =& M_{X_1}(t)M_{X_2}(t) \nonumber \\
=&\exp \Big(t\mu_1 + \frac{t^2}{2}\sigma_1^2\Big)\exp \Big(t\mu_2 + \frac{t^2}{2}\sigma_2^2\Big) \nonumber \\
=&\exp(t\mu_1)\exp(t\mu_2)\exp\Big(\frac{t^2}{2}\sigma_1^2\Big)\exp\Big(\frac{t^2}{2}\sigma_2^2\Big) \nonumber \\
=&\exp\Big(t(\mu_1 + \mu_2)+\frac{t^2}{2}(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)\Big)
\label{mgf_sum}
\end{align}
which means 
\begin{equation}
X_1 + X_2 \sim N(\mu_1+\mu_2,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)
\end{equation}
I know that the desired result, given that the variables are not independent, should be
\begin{equation}
X_1 + X_2 \sim N(\mu_1+\mu_2,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2+2cov(X_1,X_2))
\end{equation}

Is it a way to show the correct variance of the distribution of $X_1+X_2$ along the lines of the mgf derivation as above?

Comment: You need to find mgf of bivariate normal distribution $M_{X_1,X_2}(t_1,t_2)=E\left[e^{t_1X_1+t_2X_2}\right]$ by integrating joint pdf. After that take $t_1=t_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your hint @NCh. I can update the question with the way I have sketched the derivation of the theoretical distribution of $X_1 + X_2$